# Azure Web App Internal/External Access - Split DNS

Tags: networking, azure, cname-record, web-applications, split-dns

I recently deployed an **Azure Web App** and assigned **custom domain and ssl cert**. I added a CNAME DNS records to the external DNS registrar so now I can access the web app over the **internet** - webapp.company.com. The issue I noticed now is that I am **unable to access the web app** using the same URL on our **internal network**. I've tried creating an A record in our **internal DNS records** pointing to the public ip of the web app and also creating a **CNAME record** pointing to the default azure web app URL** but I can't access when connected to the **internal network**.

Is there anything I can do to be able to access the web app URL, ex: webapp.company.com from both the internal and external (internet) networks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you should need to do is create a record in your internal DNS to point to the web app CNAME or IP, as you have done. This will direct internal traffic to the right location.

If this is not working I would check that you can actually resolve the name on your internal network. If you can then look any firewalls or proxies that may be blocking acess.

Comment: Thanks for the help, appreciate it!